# quantile function for a raster stack in R seems to return incorrect values

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to calculate quantiles for a raster stack in R using `raster::quantile`. This works fine for a single raster, but applying the function to a raster stack where the rasters do not have the same NA cells results in incorrect quantile values.

Here's a reproducible example of the problem:

```
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

#create raster stack
r <-raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
r1 <- setValues(r, sample(100:2000, ncell(r), replace = TRUE))
s <- stack(r, r1)

plot(s)
```

[image: Plot of raster stack]

```
#quantiles of raster stack
quantile(s)
#>              0%      25%       50%       75%     100%
#> test.1 138.7071 293.9575  371.9001  501.0102 1736.058
#> test.2 100.0000 596.0000 1062.0000 1530.0000 2000.000

#quantiles of each raster in the stack
quantile(s[[1]])
#>        0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
#>  138.7071  293.9575  371.9001  501.0102 1736.0580

quantile(s[[2]])
#>   0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
#>  100  591 1071 1530 2000
```

As you can see, the 25% and 50% quantiles calculated using the raster stack are different for the second raster in the stack compared to using the `quantile` function on that raster directly. Note that this problem does not occur if both rasters have the same NA values, e.g.

```
quantile(stack(r1, sqrt(r1)))
#>        0%       25%        50%        75%       100%
#> test  100 585.00000 1045.50000 1537.00000 2000.00000
#> layer  10  24.18677   32.33419   39.20459   44.72136

quantile(r1)
#>     0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
#>  100.0  585.0 1045.5 1537.0 2000.0

quantile(sqrt(r1))
#>       0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
#> 10.00000 24.18677 32.33419 39.20459 44.72136
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CRAN version that you are using, if a cell is NA in one layer it is set to NA in all layers. I agree that this is not expected and I have fixed it in version 3.5-4 (currently the development version.)

```
quantile(s)
#             0%      25%       50%       75%     100%
#test.1 138.7071 293.9575  371.9001  501.0102 1736.058
#test.2 100.0000 601.0000 1061.5000 1542.0000 2000.000
```

Comment: Many thanks Robert, I appreciate you rolling out the fix.